# Unable to use LinearLayout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin.Forms and while following the following documentation of the Android Linear Layout - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout

I have received this error

> Error XLS0414 The type 'LinearLayout' was not found. Verify that you
>   are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
>   assemblies have been built.   DPM MainPage.xaml

Also in the Output window the message says

> Type LinearLayout not found in xmlns
>   http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Here is the View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DPM"
             x:Class="DPM.MainPage">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Prueba" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="Bottom" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If any more information is needed to solve this let me know using the comments

Comment: You can mixing Android AXML-based layouts vs Xamarin.Forms XAML-based. If this is a Xamarin.Forms based application you need to stick to only Forms' XAML : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no LinearLayout In Xamarin.Forms, you may be confused with Xamarin Native.

There's a list of Layouts that you can implement in Xamarin.Forms.

Also you're probably looking for StackLayout for that kind of structure

[Xamarin.Forms Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts)